# Jest Test a method in a class calls another method

Tags: typescript, testing, jestjs

I am testing a service that has methods internally, but functionality to external sources is mocked.

In my example here, I have a method that is doing some processing.  Should the validation method fail, it will send an Alert (email, other) to an external service.

I want to test that my code will call the alert when it should, but I obviously do not want it to call the external system.

```
async Process(DateToProcess: number): Promise<void> {
    const IsWeekend: boolean = IsSaturdayOrSunday(DateToProcess);
    ...
    const DataToValidate$: Array<ResponseDTO> = await this.GetData(DateToProcess);
    const IsValid$: boolean = await this.ValidateEntries(DataToValidate$);

    if (! IsValid$) {
        await this.CreateAlert('Data is Invalid');
    }
}
```

I am trying to setup the testing, and have the external services with stubs.

```
const AlertDate = new ResponseDTO();
const mockAlertService = {
    provide: AlertsService,
    useFactory: () => ({
        Create: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(AlertData),
        Delete: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(null),
        GetOne: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(AlertData),
    })
}

...
const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
    providers: [
        ValidateService,
        mockAlertService,
    ],
}).compile();

service = module.get<ValidateDailyTimeEntriesService>(ValidateDailyTimeEntriesService);
AlertssTestService = module.get<AlertsService>(AlertsService);
```

This setup works, I can mock the return values. I have other services included that I have removed here, that use the same format and load basic test data, which I can validate works.

My tests though, cannot validate that the Alert is called to be created.

```
it('should send an alert if there are no times entries and it is not a weekend', async () => {
    const spyProcess_: jest.SpyInstance = jest.spyOn(service, 'Process');
    const spyGetData_: jest.SpyInstance = jest.spyOn(service, 'GetData').mockResolvedValue(TestData);

    const spyValidateData_: jest.SpyInstance = jest.spyOn(service, 'ValidateData');
    const spyCreateAlert_: jest.SpyInstance = jest.spyOn(service, 'CreateAlert').mockResolvedValue(true);

    await service.Process(20221012); // Call the main function
    expect(spyProcess_).toHaveBeenCalled(); // These 2 calls work, were called in the this test
    expect(spyProcess_).toHaveBeenCalledWith(20221012); 

    expect(spyGetData_).toHaveBeenCalled(); // Works, this was called
    expect(spyGetData_).toHaveReturnedWith(TestData);

    expect(spyValidateData_).toHaveBeenCalled(); // This fails???
    expect(spyCreateAlert_).toHaveBeenCalled(); // This will fail as well

    spyCreateAlert_.mockClear();
    spyValidateData_.mockClear();
    spyGetData_.mockClear();
    spyProcessOneDate_.mockClear();
});
```

The error shows that the last two spies will not work, even though they appear to me to be the same style as the ones that do.

```
    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0


    > 298 |             expect(spyValidateData_).toHaveBeenCalled();

    > 298 |             expect(spyCreateAlert_).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

**EDIT**
It has to do with the async/await vs Promise handling.  If I do:

```
async Process(): Promise<void> {
    this.GetData(DateToProcess).then( (DataToValidate$: Array<ResponseDTO>) => {});
    this.CreateAlert('Data is Invalid').then( (Result$: boolean) => {});
    return;
}
```

The tests will pass.  However, using the await will fail:

```
async Process(): Promise<void> {
    const DataToValidate$: Array<ResponseDTO> = await this.GetData(DateToProcess);
    const Result$: boolean = await this.CreateAlert();
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue has to do with the processing I am doing.  await/async cannot run in loop that have callbacks, such as forEach().  Use the for..of format, will correct the errors I am encountering.  It takes some restructing of the code I have written, but it does correct the issue.

My simple example did not show the looping in the secondary functions.  Therefore, the simple re-write would be:

```
    const DataToValidate$: Array<ResponseDTO> = await this.GetData(DateToProcess);
    DataToValidate$.forEach( (OneRecord: ResponseDTO) => {
        const IsValid$: boolean = await this.ValidateEntries(OneRecord);
    }
```

However, VS Code indicates I need an async before the await

```
    const DataToValidate$: Array<ResponseDTO> = await this.GetData(DateToProcess);
    DataToValidate$.forEach(async (OneRecord: ResponseDTO) => {
        const IsValid$: boolean = await this.ValidateEntries(OneRecord);
    }
```

However, this does not work as the async in the forEach() does not work, since forEach is a callback style loop.

```
    const DataToValidate$: Array<ResponseDTO> = await this.GetData(DateToProcess);
    for (OneRecord of DataToValidate$) {
        const IsValid$: boolean = await this.ValidateEntries(OneRecord);
    }
```

This will allow the proper processing.